# Opposite of diff in MatLab

Tags: matlab

If I have the matrix `x=[x(1) x(2) x(3) ... x(n-1) x(n]`, then `diff(x)` will give
`[x(2)-x(1) x(3)-x(2) ... x(n)-x(n-1)]`. Is there such a function for addition so the result would be `[x(1)+x(2) x(2)+x(3) ... x(n-1)+x(n)]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try simply doing

```
x(2:end) + x(1:end-1)
```

Comment: I know that but was curious if there was a pre-built function for that like diff

Answer (score 4):

Convolve with `[1 1]`:

```
y = conv(x, [1 1], 'valid');
```

Comment: +1 for `conv` mainly because it requires signal processing knowledge.  The other answers are canonical, but `conv` was the approach I thought of first.

Comment: @rayryeng Our minds have been permanently spoiled by signal processing! :-)

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in function for that, but if you need to use it often, then make a separate function or an anonymous function like this

```
%// Anonymous function - can be used inside the script alone any no. of times
summ = @(x) x(2:end) + x(1:end-1);   %// Answer by nneonneo
```

**Test run:**

```
>> A = randi([1,5],1,5)

A =
 2     3     4     5     5

>> summ(A)

ans =
 5     7     9    10
```

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of diff in Matlab is [cumsum](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html).

**Example:**

```
>> A = randi([1,5],1,5)

A =

     1     3     5     2     1

>> B = diff(A)

B =

     2     2    -3    -1

>> C = cumsum([A(1) B])

C =

     1     3     5     2     1
```